# Average time between two consecutive events in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a table as shown below.

| time | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-19T17:15:05 | A |
| 2021-03-19T17:15:11 | B |
| 2021-03-19T17:15:11 | C |
| 2021-03-19T17:15:12 | A |
| 2021-03-19T17:15:14 | C |

I want to find the average time between event A and the event following it.
How do I find it using an SQL query?
here desired output is: 4 seconds.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Hi Naeaf. What database are you on?

Comment: Spark SQL (Azure databricks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is `lead()` to get the time from the next row.  Then you need to calculate the difference.  So for all rows:

```
select t.*,
       (to_unix_timestamp(lead(time) over (order by time) -
        to_unix_timestamp(time)
       ) as diff_seconds
from t;
```

Use a subquery and filtering for just `A` and the average:

```
select avg(diff_seconds)
from (select t.*,
             (to_unix_timestamp(lead(time) over (order by time) -
              to_unix_timestamp(time)
             ) as diff_seconds
      from t
     ) t
where event = 'A';
```